# Numpy building from source: RuntimeError: Broken toolchain: cannot link a simple C program

Tags: python, numpy, compiler-errors, toolchain, building

I keep getting an error when I'm trying to build numpy from source code.
This is the error:

```
running build_ext
running build_src
INFO: build_src
INFO: building py_modules sources
INFO: building library "npymath" sources
as: unrecognized option '--64'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/iulian/Downloads/numpy-1.22.0/setup.py", line 450, in <module>
    setup_package()
  File "/home/iulian/Downloads/numpy-1.22.0/setup.py", line 442, in setup_package
    setup(**metadata)
  File "/home/iulian/Downloads/numpy-1.22.0/numpy/distutils/core.py", line 169, in setup
    return old_setup(**new_attr)
  File "/home/iulian/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 153, in setup
    return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/distutils/core.py", line 148, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/distutils/dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "/home/iulian/Downloads/numpy-1.22.0/numpy/distutils/command/build_ext.py", line 101, in run
    self.run_command('build_src')
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
    self.distribution.run_command(command)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "/home/iulian/Downloads/numpy-1.22.0/numpy/distutils/command/build_src.py", line 144, in run
    self.build_sources()
  File "/home/iulian/Downloads/numpy-1.22.0/numpy/distutils/command/build_src.py", line 155, in build_sources
    self.build_library_sources(*libname_info)
  File "/home/iulian/Downloads/numpy-1.22.0/numpy/distutils/command/build_src.py", line 288, in build_library_sources
    sources = self.generate_sources(sources, (lib_name, build_info))
  File "/home/iulian/Downloads/numpy-1.22.0/numpy/distutils/command/build_src.py", line 378, in generate_sources
    source = func(extension, build_dir)
  File "numpy/core/setup.py", line 701, in get_mathlib_info
    raise RuntimeError(
RuntimeError: Broken toolchain: cannot link a simple C program.
```

My building system is **Ubuntu 18.04.6**.

I'm using **python3.9.10** to build **numpy 1.22.0**.

I need to generate the module's files to use them for an arm device, which has no internet connection.

I already tried to change the gcc/g++ version from gcc/++-6 to gcc/++-7/8

Please, if you have any idea about this, I would apreciate the help. Thanks!

**EDIT:**

I'm building numpy by cross-compiling with the following commands:
`python3 setup.py build_ext'
'python3 setup.py install --prefix=./install/'

**UPDATE**:

I solved the problem with BROKEN TOOLCHAIN, by setting the CC and CXX flags:

`export CC=arm-cortexa9-linux-gnueabi-gcc`

`export CXX=arm-cortexa9-linux-gnueabi-g++`

but i got another error:

```
/usr/lib/python3.9/distutils/dist.py:274: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'define_macros'
  warnings.warn(msg)
running build
running config_cc
unifing config_cc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --compiler options
running config_fc
unifing config_fc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --fcompiler options
running build_src
build_src
building py_modules sources
building library "npymath" sources
  adding 'build/src.linux-x86_64-3.9/numpy/core/src/npymath' to include_dirs.
None - nothing done with h_files = ['build/src.linux-x86_64-3.9/numpy/core/src/npymath/npy_math_internal.h']
building library "npyrandom" sources
building extension "numpy.core._multiarray_tests" sources
building extension "numpy.core._multiarray_umath" sources
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/iulian/Downloads/test/numpy-1.20.0/setup.py", line 513, in <module>
    setup_package()
  File "/home/iulian/Downloads/test/numpy-1.20.0/setup.py", line 505, in setup_package
    setup(**metadata)
  File "/home/iulian/Downloads/test/numpy-1.20.0/numpy/distutils/core.py", line 169, in setup
    return old_setup(**new_attr)
  File "/home/iulian/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 153, in setup
    return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/distutils/core.py", line 148, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/distutils/dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "/home/iulian/Downloads/test/numpy-1.20.0/numpy/distutils/command/build.py", line 61, in run
    old_build.run(self)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/distutils/command/build.py", line 135, in run
    self.run_command(cmd_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
    self.distribution.run_command(command)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "/home/iulian/Downloads/test/numpy-1.20.0/numpy/distutils/command/build_src.py", line 144, in run
    self.build_sources()
  File "/home/iulian/Downloads/test/numpy-1.20.0/numpy/distutils/command/build_src.py", line 161, in build_sources
    self.build_extension_sources(ext)
  File "/home/iulian/Downloads/test/numpy-1.20.0/numpy/distutils/command/build_src.py", line 318, in build_extension_sources
    sources = self.generate_sources(sources, ext)
  File "/home/iulian/Downloads/test/numpy-1.20.0/numpy/distutils/command/build_src.py", line 378, in generate_sources
    source = func(extension, build_dir)
  File "numpy/core/setup.py", line 444, in generate_config_h
    moredefs, ignored = cocache.check_types(config_cmd, ext, build_dir)
  File "numpy/core/setup.py", line 49, in check_types
    out = check_types(*a, **kw)
  File "numpy/core/setup.py", line 294, in check_types
    raise SystemError(
SystemError: Cannot compile 'Python.h'. Perhaps you need to install python-dev|python-devel.
```

I'm using an arm cross compiler: **arm-cortexa9-linux-gnueabi**

The error says that I have to install python-dev(python3-dev in my situation). But I already installed both with: `sudo apt-get install python3-dev python-dev` and still not working.

Comment: Please walk us through how you try to build `numpy`.

Comment: AFAICS Ubuntu 18 comes with Python-3.6. How did you get Python-3.9? https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/python3

Comment: Since you figured out the original problem, please open a new question for the header file issue. This helps other people with the same issue to find the right solution.